# ??? appears in references

Tags: citing, springer

I am using Springer's latex style and having this problem. I just copied my content from Elsevier's format to here but now I see "???" in some references, like:

> References

> [1] Branke, J.: Evolutionary Optimization in Dynamic Environments vol. 3. Springer, ??? (2012)

However, it must be like this:

> [1]  J.  Branke,  Evolutionary optimization in dynamic environments,Vol. 3, Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

Relevant bib entry:

```
@book{branke2012evolutionary,
  title={Evolutionary optimization in dynamic environments},
  author={Branke, J{\"u}rgen},
  volume={3},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}
```

I am using `sn-mathphys.bst` file as the style file. And I think I have found the relevant lines in this file:

```
FUNCTION {format.pub.address}
{ publisher empty$
  howpublished empty$
  and
    { 
    address empty$
      'skip$
        {   volume empty$
            'insert.comma
            'new.sentence
          if$
          address
          type$ "inproceedings" =
            {"conflocation"}
            {"location"}
           if$  
          make.tag output
        }
      if$
    }
    { 
      address empty$
        {   publisher empty$
            {howpublished} 
            {springer.publisher} 
          if$ 
           "publisher" make.tag
          #1 bother =
            {", \blocation{???}" *  } % <=== THIS LINE
            'skip$
           if$
           output   
        }
        {
          publisher empty$
            {howpublished } 
            {springer.publisher } 
           if$ 
          "publisher" make.tag output
          insert.comma
          address "location" make.tag output
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

It seems it requires some address line which doesn't come when I copy from google scholar.

And yes, I already copied my `.bib` file to Springer's folder on my Overleaf account. So what is the problem here?

Comment: Please edit your posting to show the contents of the bib entry in question.

Comment: I did what you asked for.

Comment: Please list exactly which style you're using, I think Springer may have many styles. In general it might be a good idea to provide a small sample program that others can copy and test. Then we can see which class, preamble and bibtex style you're using.

Comment: @daleif check again.

Comment: Instead of going into the `.bst` please provide a test doc we can use for testing. It might be as simple as your bib data is incomplete because this `.bst` expects more data than you have given.

Comment: @daleif My bib data is working perfectly in any other format. The problem is with the Springer's bst files. I have used all of them, still erroring. Anyway, I am going to try bypass the above line in the bst file. Maybe it works.

Comment: As I said the mandatory fields varies from `.bst` to `.bst`, so again it is more likely that data is missing from your data

Comment: BTW: where exactly have you gotten that `.bst`? It is not a "known" one

Answer (score 1):

This .bst file requires the address field to be used. The following example should help:

```
@book{branke2012evolutionary,
  title={Evolutionary optimization in dynamic environments},
  author={Branke, J{\"u}rgen},
  volume={3},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media},
  address={}
}
```